# How to run sql script as AAD user from Build pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines

I'm setting up Managed Identity for my web app. As part of deployment I'm deploying database, run migrations and I also need to add the managed identity user with this script

```
CREATE USER [<identity-name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
GO
```

as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi#grant-permissions-to-managed-identity). I do this using Azure SQL Database deployment task. The problem I have is that this has to be executed as a Azure AD user.

> Principal 'xyz' could not be created. Only connections established
>   with Active Directory accounts can create other Active Directory
>   users.

I don't want to use my account and I can't create new user accounts other than Guest users.

Is there any other option than to create user in Azure AD first and then provide it's login and password (stored as secure variable or in my Azure KeyVault)?

Comment: Run it from an Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI task using a service principal that is already authorized to manage the database.

Comment: I don't understand. You mean those two are tasks in Azure build pipelines? But who will be authorized to to manage database? It will again be me or some other account?

Comment: Creating service connection to Azure behind the scene ServicePrincipal is created to manage Azure resources. It allows Azure DevOps make a changes on Azure resources.

Comment: I create resources using ARM templates, I deploy code, I run migrations so I think I already have this ServicePrincipal created right? But so far looks to me like I need something special for this task.